# Photoshop - I need to batch resize 20 images. I need pngs

Tags: png, photoshop

I have searched and almost found the answer.

```
File > script > Image processor > Select folder > resize to fit
```

But, I can't see the option to save as png format (as you can see from my screenshot - using photoshop CC 2017)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: If the answer by @Reystleen has helped you, you need to accept the answer.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by creating an `action` and then `batch processing`:

**A. Create the action**

1. Open file in Photoshop
2. Start recording
3. `File > Save As > set file type to png`
4. Click Save
5. Stop recording and save your action (***Save as png*** for example)

**B. Process your files**

1. Select all your files
2. `Tools > Photoshop > Batch`
3. Select your ***Save as png*** action
4. Click Ok to process

Comment: Excellent. Thank you very much.